# Facebook(4.6)/Parse(1.9.1) Login not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I was using a both facebook and parse as part of my log in process fine - however I updated both to the most recent version (facebook 4.6 and parse 1.9.1) yesterday and now my app's log in process no longer works.

I call the parse util method to migrate an anon user:

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser]
                  withReadPermissions:permissionsArray
                                block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
```

The Facebook login process is started with via SFSafariViewController - credentials are input and I submit these - and am then presented with a white screen and the SFSafariViewController is not dismissed - there is no callback from the pfutils method either.
[image: facebook after credentials entered]

I have followed the iOS9 migration guide and have the following set up in my plist

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>fbauth2</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb{idhere}</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>{idhere}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am an idiot - I must have removed pasted over the app delegate method which prevented this 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
}

Comment: So that resolved the issue for you did it?

Comment: Yes - thanks for some reason I couldnt answer the question myself originally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot - I must have removed pasted over the app delegate method which prevented this -

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation { return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation ]; }
```